# what is network manager script dispatcher service?

Tags: syslog

[image]

The message in the picture above is intermittently recorded in syslog. Why does the network manager script dispatcher service keep restarting?

Even if you search, even the role of the service cannot be properly checked.

Ubuntu version: 20.04

Comment: A little more information will be required to provide a possible answer. Could you [edit] the question to include the version of Ubuntu you're running and how often you see this issue? 

Comment: ubuntu version is 20.04, The frequency is about once every 2 hours.

Comment: Please add the output from `systemctl status NetworkManagerDispatcher` if available.

Comment: Strangely, a message appears indicating that the service is not running. Why?

Comment: @matigo
First of all, I am very curious as to what the above syslog means.
What happens when networkmanagerdispatcher starts?

Comment: Hello. Please do not post pictures of text. Include the text in the body of the question. As you yourself noticed the picture cut off part of the information. Alos pictures can be hard to read.